# Sensor to measure distance of moving object

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

I am wondering the best type of sensor I can use to measure the distance between a  moving object and a fixed object, i.e. the sensor. For application, think of a moving car going around a corner with a barrier in place. Ideally, the measurement would be somewhat accurate down to at least a centimeter.

I have looked into both small lidar and ultrasonic sensors, leaning towards the lidar given the environment would be loud, but am looking for other types of sensors if something more practical is available.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: My Mercedes SUV has  5 or so buttons both bumpers with an left-right LED bar graph sensor and beeeps on Red. I starts around 40cm and Red is about a dozen cm using piezo ultrasound.  But ice and SNOW also triggers it over sensor. while the latest models use 4 corner wide angle cameras to give a virtual top down looking view around the vehicle. on dash display.

Answer (score 1):

**Ultrasound**. You've already mentioned this, it's probably going to be the best choice.  I would be surprised if ambient noise was a big problem, but it does depend what that noise is.

**Lidar**. You mentioned this one too.  I don't know much about it but I daresay it's expensive.

**Laser triangulation**. I would expect this to have the same advantages as lidar, but be cheaper.

**Light gates**. Cheap and reliable, but probably poor resolution unless you buy a lot of them and you have to put transmitters/receivers on both sides of where the car is going.

**Capacitance**. You can have a large panel on the wall and detect the distance to a (metal) car or truck.  I've seen it done, but it's probably not a good choice for most of the time. Different cars will produce different responses.

**Image recognition**. Probably only cost effective if you already have CCTV in place. But modern computerised image recognition can achieve a lot more than you might think.

Comment: Thanks Jack. In doing some research, many of the ultrasonic sensors I can find do not measure at close range – 6 inches seems to be the cutoff. Do you know if they are capable of measuring at very short distances?

Comment: PING ultrasonic sensor from Parallax has 2cm-3m range